# Delete column in SQL that contains dots and squared brackets

Tags: sql, sql-server, rename, sql-delete

How can one delete a column name `[database].[dbo].[my_table].[col_name]` in SQL server, that is a column name with dots and squared brackets. In other words, it is the column name that I wanted but prefixed by the database name and shema.
I tried many combinations based on internet e.g. [here](http://sqlhints.com/tag/rename-column-name-with-square-brackets/) but didn't succeed.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to _rename_ the column or _delete it_? the link there confuse me a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand if you want to rename this column or drop it, but here is how to do both

```
CREATE TABLE JustTest(
  Col1 INT,
  [[database]].[dbo]].[my_table]].[col_name]]] INT
);

-- To rename the column use this
EXEC sp_rename 'JustTest.[[database]].[dbo]].[my_table]].[col_name]]]', 
               'NewName', 
               'COLUMN';

-- If the table is TempTable use this
EXEC tempdb.sys.sp_rename N'#TMP.[[database]].[dbo]].[my_table]].[col_name]]]',
                N'NewName',
                N'COLUMN';

-- To drop it use this
ALTER TABLE JustTest DROP COLUMN [[database]].[dbo]].[my_table]].[col_name]]];
```

Answer (score 1):

In a delimited identifier ']' is escaped as ']]', '[' and '.' don't need to be escaped.

So like this:

```
create table #tt(id int, [[database]].[dbo]].[my_table]].[col_name]]] int)

alter table #tt drop column [[database]].[dbo]].[my_table]].[col_name]]]
```